# Directing Specific Emails to AWS and Others to Google Gmail

Tags: amazon-web-services, email, gmail, amazon-ses, google-workspace

All employees in my company have their Google Workspace email addresses, such as `example@business.io`. We utilize `info@business.io` for sending emails using **AWS SES**. Presently, we aim to have customer replies directed to our **S3 bucket** storage. These replies will consistently come to `info@business.io`.

Initially, the MX record is set up for Google. However, to route emails to `info@business.io` through AWS, I must add AWS's **MX record**. Upon doing so, my **S3 bucket** successfully receives emails, but Google ceases to receive emails intended for other employee addresses.

In summary, I seek to have AWS receive emails specifically designated for `info@business.io`, while all other emails should be directed to Gmail.

Comment: DNS MX records work at the domain level.   If the users are `@` the same domain (eg `@business.io`), there is no way to route mail differently at the DNS MX level.  You have 2 options: differentiate the domain (info@notify.business.io) to route the mail at the DNS MX layer, or pass the mail to a destination on a different domain after delivery to google.

Comment: you mean I can create subdomain notify.business.io and receive emails on info@notify.business.io on S3 and *@business.io emails on gmail as usual?

Comment: Yep.  You'll have to configure SES to use the subdomain, then you can add an MX record for the subdomain to the existing dns zone (no need to delegate the subdomain in dns)

Comment: Thanks it worked as expected @erik258.